# SAS Proc SQL to add a constant to a variable

Tags: sas, greenplum

I have a SAS dataset with numeric variables `to`, `from`, and `weight`.  Some of the observations have value 0 for `weight`.  I need all the `weight` values to be positive, so I wish to simply add 1 to all `weight` values.

How can I do that using Proc SQL?

I have tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
proc sql;
    update mylib.mydata
        set weight=weight+1;
quit;
```

The error is:

```
ERROR: A CURRENT-OF-CURSOR operation cannot be initiated because
the column "weight" cannot be used to uniquely identify a row
because of its data type.
```

Also, `mylib` refers to a Greenplum appliance.  This might be the problem...

Comment: Perhaps you should let us know how it doesn't work?  That code works fine for me as is.  (`data test;
do x = 1 to 10;
weight=2;
output;
end;
run;

proc sql;
update test
  set weight=weight+1;
quit;
` for example).

Comment: Sorry, I should have showed the error message.  Post edited.

Comment: That sounds like a DBMS-specific error indeed.  SAS is willing to do this operation, but presumably your Greenplum whatnot is complaining.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the database permissions to update that table, you might want to use the SAS/Access pass-through facility.  You will need to know the correct syntax for this to work.  Here is a non-working example:

```
proc sql;
  connect to greenplm as dbcon
    (server=greenplum04 db=sample port=5432 user=gpusr1 password=gppwd1);
  execute (
     /* Native code goes here */

     update sample.mydata
        set weight=weight+1   

   ) by dbcon;
quit;
```

The connection string would be the same as used on the `LIBNAME` that defined your "mylib' libref.

However, if you are really trying to create a SAS dataset (not update the real table), you can do that with a simple data step:

```
data mydata;
   set mylib.mydata
   weight = weight + 1;
run;
```

That will create a **copy** of the table that can be used with other SAS procedures.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this note](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/9081) at prosgress.com. You probably need to add `UPDATE_MULT_ROWS=YES` to your library definition.